# How can I make TypeScript deconstruct function parameter, assign default value, and optional whole object type at same time?

Tags: typescript

Please see this minimum function

```
function addX({ num = 1 }) {
  return num + 1;
}
```

The above function has done two things

1. Deconstruct function parameter
2. Assign default value

Now, I can use the function like this:

```
add({ num: 2 }); // valid
add({}); // valid
```

However, I can't use it like this

```
add(); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0
```

I can't find a way to tell TypeScript the whole object is optional

```
// Invalid
function add({ num = 1 }?) {
  return num + 1;
}

// Invalid
function add({ num = 1 }?: { num: number }) {
  return num + 1;
}
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this

```
function addX({ num = 1 } = {num: 1}) {
  return num + 1;
}

addX() // returns 2

addX({}) // returns 2

addX({num: 2}) // returns 3
```

Comment: Neat! I think this is the only way.

Comment: Even easier as `function addX({ num = 1 } = {})` since you already have a default value for `num`